# AWK: What is the regular expression to match any string?

Tags: regex, awk

> I assume the regular expression would be the same in any case (eg:
>   `grep`), but I am testing this using `awk`.

Case **example**:

```
$ cat Test.csv
2018-03-31,22:39,Test,2,4,2
2018-03-31,22:40,Test02,2,4,2
2018-03-31,22:40,Test03,2,4,2
2018-03-31,22:40,Test04,2,4,2
2018-03-31,22:59,Test03,5,4,2
2018-03-31,23:00,Test07,6,4,2
2018-03-31,23:00,Test08,2,2,2
```

I would like to know how to **match any value** (any string) at, say, field 3:

```
$ awk -F ',' '$3 == *' Test.csv
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
        $3 == >>>  * <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

-

```
$ awk -F ',' '$3 == .*' Test.csv
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
        $3 == >>>  . <<< *
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

-

```
$ awk -F ',' '$3 == /*/' Test.csv
awk: illegal primary in regular expression * at
 source line number 1
 context is
        $3 == >>>  /*/ <<<
```

-

```
$ awk -F ',' '$3 == /.*/' Test.csv
[No results]
```

-

```
$ awk -F ',' '$3 == /^*/' Test.csv
[No results]
```

Even when there could be other methods to solve the problem, how can I **match every possible string** by using **regular expressions** at a specific field (CSV assumed) by using AWK?

If possible, it could be useful some method to include the NUL string (for empty fields like `2018-03-31,23:00,,2,2,2`) so AWK returns every line.

---

**Why do I need this**?

> (upon requestion; a bit awkward to explain, sorry; only for those
>   interested)

Basically for code simplification (readability). My shell script is structured in a manner that I would prefer to execute the search like this:

```
awk -F ',' -v AL__AWK="$AL" -v VL__AWK="$VL" -v DL__AWK="$DL" -v Codigo__AWK="$Codigo" -v SubCodigo__AWK="$SubCodigo" '$4 == AL__AWK && $5 == VL__AWK && $6 == DL__AWK && $8 ~ Codigo__AWK && $9 ~ SubCodigo__AWK' "$LogFile"
```

As can be seen (er... or so I hope) the search for fields inside the CSV file is variable-based. Some of these variables are initialized with a specific value and some come from parameter input. So, having a generic "any string" value would prevent me from writing this AWK line in multiple different manners.

I.E: Sometimes the script will receive the `Codigo=Ptt` value via input parameter , and some the `Codigo` variable will not be defined by parameter inputing; in this second case, I will do `Codigo=".*"`, so the above AWK line will still be valid.

Sorry, but the complete explanation is very long.

Comment: The regexp comparison operator is `~`, not `==`. If you include the expected output given that input and explain why you're trying to match a string against a regexp that'll match any string then we can help you.

Comment: Indeed, @EdMorton , the `~` solved the problem. You should post it as an answer to the problem. It works even for empty/NUL fields. Thanks you.

Comment: But the question `how can I match every possible string by using regular expressions at a specific field` makes no sense on it's own - matching is a precursor to DOING something when the string matches the regexp so what is it you want to do and why? Do you want to print the matching field or print the whole line when the field matches or something else? What is the point of matching on "anything or nothing" when that condition is always true? This sounds very much like an XY Problem.

Comment: Your arguments have, indeed, some logic, @EdMorton . I have edited the original question to reflect. The main purpose is harder to explain, but this method for using AWK would make a confortable and readable programming in my script. If not, I would need to nest multiple AWK cases.

Comment: You seem to be confused about regex. `.` matches any single character and `*` repeats the previous regular expression zero or more times. So `*` alone is a syntax error because there is no previous regex to repeat (and though `/.*/` will match any string, so will `//`, so you should probably just use that).

Comment: It worked! But, when using an **internal AWK variable** for the regexp pattern (as described in the original question), it seems I must remove the `/`, so, after  `foo=""`, I found `awk -F ',' -v foo__AWK="$foo" '$3 ~ /foo__AWK/' Test.csv` yields no results, but `awk -F ',' -v foo__AWK="$foo" '$3 ~ foo__AWK' Test.csv` gives the correct equivalent to `foo=".*"` result (well... I am not very experienced on AWK syntax, and I didn't know that). Thanks you, @triplee.

Comment: `/../` are regexp literal delimiters, just like `"..."` are string literal delimiters. When doing a regexp comparison using `~` you can compare a string on the left side against either a regexp literal `x ~ /foo/` or a string literal `x ~ "foo"` or a variable `{var="foo"} x ~ var`. When you write `$3 ~ /foo_AWK/` you're doing a regexp comparison against the literal characters `foo_AWK` not against a variable of that name. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49598866/1745001) for how to do a regexp comparison against a possibly empty variable as you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

As easy as (note the `~` instead of the `==` operator):

```
$ awk -F ',' '$3 ~ /.*/' Test.csv
2018-03-31,22:39,Test,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:40,Test02,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:40,Test03,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:40,Test04,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:59,Test03,5,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,23:00,Test07,6,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,23:00,Test08,2,2,2,,,
```

Without explaining the reasons to do this kind of search (original poster told it was harsh to describe), it seems just some sort of academic question, but I guess someone could probably need it someday.

For the case (as explained on the question) of using **variables as a pattern**:

```
$ foo="03"
$ awk -F ',' -v foo__AWK="$foo" '$3 ~ foo__AWK' Test.csv
2018-03-31,22:40,Test03,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:59,Test03,5,4,2,,,

$ foo=".*"
$ awk -F ',' -v foo__AWK="$foo" '$3 ~ foo__AWK' Test.csv
2018-03-31,22:39,Test,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:40,Test02,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:40,Test03,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:40,Test04,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:59,Test03,5,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,23:00,Test07,6,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,23:00,Test08,2,2,2,,,

$ foo=""
$ awk -F ',' -v foo__AWK="$foo" '$3 ~ foo__AWK' Test.csv
2018-03-31,22:39,Test,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:40,Test02,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:40,Test03,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:40,Test04,2,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,22:59,Test03,5,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,23:00,Test07,6,4,2,,,
2018-03-31,23:00,Test08,2,2,2,,,
```

So, `.*` works like `` as "match any pattern" regexp.

Answer (score 1):

@SopalajodeArrierez now I see your rationale I understand what it is you're trying to do and you don't need to come up with a regexp that matches any string, your unset shell variable already IS such a regexp. Look:

```
$ echo 'a' | awk -v x='.*' '$1 ~ x'
a

$ echo 'a' | awk -v x='' '$1 ~ x'
a
```

So if your shell variable is unset, just leave it unset as any string will partially match the null string on a regexp comparison.

Comment: Mmm... your answer seems to be logical, Ed. Actually the variable is not unset, it has `y=""` value, but results seem to be the same when tested in your example. Thanks you.

Comment: You've lost me again. You said `Sometimes the script will receive the Codigo=Ptt value via input parameter , and some the Codigo variable will not be defined by parameter inputing`. In the code `-v Codigo__AWK="$Codigo"` does `$Codigo` have a value or not? If it has the value `y=<something>` how does that relate to the input data you're trying to search in? Please just edit your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output plus a clear statement of your needs if you'd like help.

Comment: I have edited my answer (not my question) to reflect the case of using variables (`$Codigo` could, as normal in a variable, have a value, but its default value is `Codigo=""`). Hope it will clarify.

Comment: What you added to your answer is exactly what I expected when I wrote my answer so I still don't understand your comment that `the variable is not unset, it has y="" value`.

Comment: At the beginning of my script, I have a `Codigo=""` line. I don't know for sure if this is a good practice on shell scripting. I preferred to unsetting the `Codigo` variable, as long as at least I know it has an empty value.

Comment: Functionally it doesn't make any difference for our purposes. When you get to the code that says `awk -v Codigo__AWK="$Codigo" ...` the awk variable `Codigo_AWK` contains the null string either way and will behave as I described when used in a regexp comparison.